# What does nextDate under opening_hours.periods.open/close.nextDate returned by Google Places API mean?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

The Place Details that is returned by a query to Google Places API returns among other things opening_hours for a place. Under opening_hours>periods>open/close there is a key called nextDate which is weird number - what does that correspond to?